# How to change background colour of overview button in android.(Android Studio)

Tags: android-styles, android-studio-3.0

How to change colour of overview button using style.xml file in android Studio.

Comment: Hi Kaushik, Welcome to SO! The question you are asking is too broad and very much opinion based. There may be lot of valid ways to achieve which can be found via google search. Therefore not suited for SO.

Comment: Please consider adding some code, explain what the code does, and in what way, precisely, that is different from what you want it to do. You will have better chances of question not getting closed.